# What exactly is a "bus" on a Behringer Xenyx mixer?

Tags: mixing

I'm looking to buy a [Behringer Xenyx 802](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J5XS3C) which is an 8-Input 2-Bus mixer.

My question is.. what does it mean by "2-bus"?

I understand the concept of the word "bus" in this context as to mean sending multiple inputs to a single track, but how is this implemented in this device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A buss is an additional output from the channels.  They are very important in live sound.

Your mixer has eight pre-amps.  Each pre-amp feeds a variable amp controlled by the gain slider or knob.  That feeds the main (stereo) mix.  Then you can control a feed to auxiliary busses through separate controls.  You can feed one or more inputs to the aux buss, and there is a separate gain control for each.  According to the [manual](http://www.behringer.com/EN/downloads/pdf/502_P0576_M_EN.pdf), yours would go to an effects output for external processing.

The aux buss can feed an internal effects channel, an aux output, or, on a bigger mixer, get mixed into the mains through a separate slider.  I do mostly live sound.  I use the main buss for the house speakers, and I use an aux buss for recording.  A grand piano doesn't really need any amplification (and the pianist might get upset if you try), but I mic the piano and only feed it to the recorder on the aux buss.  If I were recording a drum set, I would mic each piece of the set and balance all eight or so channels on a buss.  Then I could use a single control to mix that buss into the main mix without changing the balance.